# React input value through state in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a recipe app. Currently I have a popup box when you want to add a recipe. In this popup I am wanting to store the input upon confirming you want to add the recipe. I looked into the value event target methods but I believe I'm having trouble getting it to work since the state for this popup box is accessed through a component higher up (the main app component).

GitHub link: https://github.com/jeffm64/recipe-box2/tree/master/src/components

This is what I currently have to try and make it work but this results in the popup box no longer coming up. This is the state in the main app component along with handleChange:

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            recipes: [],
            addRecipeVisibility: false,
            editRecipeVisibility: false,
            value: ""
        };
},

handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
},
```

This is the popup box's input JSX:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.props.handleChange} />
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code that shows the interaction between your components?

Comment: Yeah I can do that. I actually just realized i didn't press enter on my latest push to GitHub so I can definitely see the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got your question correctly, but i will try to give you an Answer.

You're trying to pass the state of the current component to the input. As far as i could see you haven't defined a state. Use a constructor and create a default state.

You can then pass this.state.value to the input.

Also, if changes to the input are handled by the parent component and stored in that components state, you should be passing the value as a prop to the child component. In this case, no constructor is needed.

Comment: Well the value state is in the parent component. I tried doing it through props with the onChange but I haven't been able to get a result. It may be because the "this.state.value" i have for value isn't a prop as well but I wasn't quite sure where to go with the piece.

Comment: If value is in the state of the parent, then you must pass it in as a prop and then assign the prop to the input value.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for the help!